# Problem with calling a stored procedure from my c# code

Tags: c#, sql, enterprise-library

I want to run a sp from my code. the sp name stored in a db. I pass the parameters via a dictionary. this code is one of my wcf service methods that host in a windows service. my code is :

```
    private DataSet RunReport(int id, ParameterDictionary parametersDic)
    {
        DataSet result = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            DataSet report = GetReportDataset(id);

            if (report.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string reportType = GetReportTypeDataset(Convert.ToInt32(report.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ReportTypeID"]));

                if (reportType != ReportType.StoredProcedure.ToString())
                {
                    throw new Exception("your report is not a sp report.");
                }

                using (DbCommand paramCommand = DatabaseManager.Database.GetStoredProcCommand(report.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SQLQuery"].ToString()))
                {
                    foreach (var parameter in parametersDic)
                    {
                        DatabaseManager.Database.SetParameterValue(paramCommand, parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                    }
                    result = DatabaseManager.Database.ExecuteDataSet(paramCommand);
                    result.AcceptChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When I run this code the below error is accured:

> An SqlParameter with ParameterName 'ID' is not contained by this
>   SqlParameterCollection.

In addition, when I call this method via win forms every thing is ok.
what is the problem?

Comment: you can run each sp that you want with this method.

Comment: GetStoredProcCommand is one of enterprise library methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748721%28v=pandp.31%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to add the parameters before setting them:

foreach param ...
{
   DatabaseManager.Database.AddInParameter(paramCommand, `<name>`, `<DbType>`);

DatabaseManager.Database.SetParameterValue(paramCommand, parameter.Key, parameter.Value);

}